# How to merge two form classes at designtime?

Tags: delphi

I have several inheritance levels for a form class and I would like to merge two of them.

```
TMyFormA = class(TForm)
  // X
end;

TMyFormB = class(TMyFormA)
  // Y
end;
```

I need to merge `TMyFormA` and `TMyFormB` into an unique class, in order to have a `TMyFormMerged` type which will include everything comes from `TMyFormA` and `TMyFormB` (fields, visual components, events....).

```
TMyFormMerged = class(TForm)
  // X
  // Y
end;
```

Is there an automatic embedded functionality or any other thing that can help doing it?

Comment: Yes, there is embedded functionality. Ctrl+C and then Ctrl +V

Comment: If this is meant for A -> B then it my be better to use Ctrl-X and Ctrl-V for the components. Otherwise you end with doubled components in Form B that need different names.

Comment: I can do that for common components, but I also have DevExpress TdxRibbon with a lot of items, which doesn't allow Ctrl+C/Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V

Comment: If you cannot directly copy paste components then opening form as text and copying that text will do the trick (usually). If I remember correctly, inherited controls will be marked with inherited instead of object in dfm, so you will need to change that.

Comment: Sorry, imo your amended q is even less clear than it was before.  
If TFormA has X and TFormB descends from TFormA and adds X, TFormB 
already **has** X as well as Y so what **exactly** are you expecting "merging" to achieve that is any different?

Comment: @MartynA: In the second code part, the parent class is `TForm`, so the resulting class should should have the same characteristics of current `TMyFormB` but there should be one inheritance level less. Anyhow, I've updated the question again trying to be more clearer

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any existing form as the base class (i.e., immediate ancestor) of a new form,
and this will follow the usual rules of inheritance, including all its components, etc.  Try
this:

- Open a project containing FormA
- Go to File | New | Other and, under Inheritable Items, select FormA
- Delphi will create a new FormA2, which you can rename to FormB.  Obviously if your existing FromB has any components of its own, you can copy those to FormA2 and re-establish any FormB-specific event handlers.

Comment: Doing this way will create an exact clone of the current `TMyFormB` class, which is not what I need (I already have `TMyFormB` inheriting from `TMyFormA`, but I need to merge them into an unique class). I've updated the question trying to be more clear